# How can i export app reviews of an app from Apple App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store, review

I am trying to extract / export App reviews of my App on Apple App Store from my iPhone 11 pro. What are the steps to extract the reviews.

Answer (score 0):

I use [AppWage for MacOS](https://www.appwage.com/). You login with your developer Apple ID and it downloads all sales and reviews.